# Subst'd network share won't show up correctly

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-share

Even when I map a network drive with `subst` it works correctly, but shows up with a big red X in the Explorer. Does this happen, because the command is deprecated?

I can access the drive w/o any problems, even writing / creating folders and files works.

Comment: What happens when you map using net use or via Windows Explorer?

Comment: Everything works great w/o that red X. I know, it's a working and better alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So then, yes.  Given that the other, non-deprecated commands map the drive properly without the red X, it's a function of that command, likely because it has been largely deprecated.